# How can I use Polly for retries with a cancellation token?

Tags: c#, polly

I'm new to Polly so there may be a completely different approach compared to the one I'm trying to do and that would be perfectly OK.

My goals are this:

1. `token` may be canceled due to timeout or request
2. Retry forever until either success or `token` is canceled.
3. When requesting cancellation waits should be exited immediately

Although the method I have worked it seems like I'm missing something and there's probably a better/cleaner way to accomplish what I want.  I'm specifically thinking of this line `.WaitAndRetryForever(retryAttempt => TimeSpan.Zero,`.  I feel like I should be able to pass `retryDelay` in here instead of `TimeSpan.Zero` but if I do that when cancellation is requested it doesn't return until the `retryDelay` has completed waiting rather than immediately like I want.

I did see that the .Execute looks like it can do something with a cancellation token but I couldn't figure out how to use that so if that's my answer please ignore my other ramblings.

Just in case one of the Polly NuGet developers sees this what I expected to see was an overload for `WaitAndRetryForever` that took a cancellation token as a parameter so that it could return immediately if it were canceled.  I hesitate to make that an official suggestion because I'm so new to Polly I'm not sure if that makes sense.

This is the method I'm currently using:

```
internal static void Retry(Action action, TimeSpan retryDelay, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        Policy
            .Handle<IOException>()
            .WaitAndRetryForever(retryAttempt => TimeSpan.Zero,
                (ex, delay, context) =>
                {
                    Task.Delay(retryDelay, token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    //Log exception here
                })
            .Execute(() =>
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                action.Invoke();
            });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //Log cancellation here
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception here
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An overload of `Execute` takes a `CancellationToken`:

```
.Execute((ct) =>
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    action.Invoke();
}, token);
```

This token will also be applied to the delay handled within `WaitAndRetryForever`.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/orCv63)

Comment: I didn't know how to read the IntelliSense. I had tried putting `token` in the right spot where you put it but I wasn't adding the `ct` for the local variable.  Seems kind obvious now that I see it.  Thanks